# Aquaresizer doesn't work

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to include the aquaresize script in my theme. I have added it to `assets/components/aq_resize.php`

And required it in `functions.php`

```
require_once( 'assets/components/aq_resize.php' );
```

However, when I try to echo

```
aq_resize($img_url,$width);
```

Nothing is shown on the page, I gave the variables $img_url a url and $width a number

When I make a `console.log` in `assets/components/aq_resize.php` I can see the log in my console.

Why doesn't my aq_resizer work?

The aqua resizer code can be found here: https://github.com/syamilmj/Aqua-Resizer/blob/master/aq_resizer.php

To test it I used a random image from google.

```
<?php 
 $img_url = 'http://joombig.com/demo-extensions1/images/gallery_slider/Swan_large.jpg';
 $width = 300;
 echo aq_resize($img_url,$width); 
?>
```

Comment: Have you looked at the error log?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the tip, I just did, I got this error: 

[27-Apr-2016 08:58:59 UTC] Aq_Resize.process() error: Unable to resize image because image_resize_dimensions() failed

Comment: For some reason [image_resize_dimensions](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/image_resize_dimensions) is returning `false`. - Do you have the GD library installed?

Comment: It looks like it is installed http://prntscr.com/axfxf5 I use MAMP on a mac.

Comment: @Radu033 Did you fix the error?

Comment: @Bora it was 2 years ago ) I fixed it but don't remember how exactly, I never had issues with it afterwards

Answer (score 0):

Some common issues that prevent aq_resizer.php working:

1. Make sure that the original image has dimensions larger than the new dimensions you want to resize to.
2. Go to your wordpress admin dashboard > Settings > Media, and make sure that your media library folder is simply 'wp_content/uploads'. (If there is no field available to set the folder, then it's already set to 'wp_content/uploads')

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem by activating "**gd**" library for xampp. You simply have to install/activate gd library. Go to `php.ini` file and check if "**extension=gd**" starts with "**;**". If it starts with ";" simply remove it. Otherwise insert a new line `extension=gd`.